# Which mobile devices do you NOT optimize mobile responsive for?

Tags: responsive-design, mobile-first

Which mobile devices do you NOT optimize mobile responsive for?

For example chrome dev tools no longer has Pixel 1.

Which is the industry standard to create for or  leave out ?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is missing the point.

The idea of being responsive means that the site/app adapts to clearly display its contents at *any reasonable size*.

Designing for each individual device vastly increases the development and testing effort required for no real benefit, is unsustainable and impractical given the sheer number of new devices being produced, and is entirely needless. The devices themselves are essentially interchangeable at this point.